# How to use axios to `fetch all()`

Tags: axios, promise.all

I don't understand how to use axios to fetch data from an array of urls.  But I can do it with `fetch`.  The following code works perfectly:

```js
const url = 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url='

async index(videoUrls = []) {
  try {
    const response = await Promise.all(
      //        videoUrls.map(videoUrl => axios.$get(`${url}${encodeURIComponent(videoUrl)}`))
      videoUrls.map(videoUrl => fetch(`${url}${encodeURIComponent(videoUrl)}`))
    )
    const results = await Promise.all(response.map(r => r.json()));
    return results;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

When I make a call like `index(["https://vimeo.com/216850224", "https://vimeo.com/642263700"])`, my console shows an array with all the video meta details vimeo has to give me.  This is perfect.

But the moment I comment out the line that uses `fetch` and use `axios`, I get a `CORS` error.

What is the idiomatic way to fetch data from a bunch of urls in axios?

---

EDIT

I also tried this, but the `.all()` function doesn't seem to exist

```js
async index(videoUrls = []) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.all(videoUrls.map(videoUrl => `${url}${encodeURIComponent(videoUrl)}`));
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is it `axios.$get()` in your question and not simply [axios.get()](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro#axios-get-url-config) (ie, why the dollar-sign)? Also, exactly what _"CORS error"_ do you get?

Comment: Any reason you want to use Axios over `fetch()`? Personally, I'd prefer the latter since it's browser-native

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it like below:

```js
(async function getAll() {

  const axiosrequest1 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const axiosrequest2 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const axiosrequest3 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

  const [res1, res2, res3] = await Promise.all([axiosrequest1, axiosrequest2, axiosrequest3]);
  console.log('request1', res1.data);
  console.log('request2', res2.data);
  console.log('request3', res3.data);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Phil my bad! Updated my answer. You can easily replace `axios.all` with `Promise.all` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Axios version would be slightly different because it automatically decodes and embeds the response body into the `response.data` property (no need for `res.json()`)

```js
const baseUrl = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json"

const index = async (videoUrls = []) => {
  // create an array of responses and wait for them to resolve
  const responses = await Promise.all(
    videoUrls.map(url => axios.get(baseUrl, { params: { url } })
  )

  // extract the `data` properties and return them as an array
  return responses.map(({ data }) => data)
}
```

---

Exactly when you extract `response.data` is totally up to you. It could also look like this

```js
const index = (videoUrls = []) => Promise.all(
  videoUrls.map(async (url) => (
    await axios.get(baseUrl, { params: { url } })
  ).data)
)
```

---

FYI, your `fetch()` version could be a little cleaner too...

```js
const baseUrl = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json"

const index = (videoUrls = []) => Promise.all(
  videoUrls.map(async (url) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams({ url })
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}?${params}`)
    if (!res.ok) { // check for bad response
      throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
    }
    return res.json()
  })
)
```